# Handling ajax success response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

PHP: lockState.php

```
require '../dbconn.php';
$query = mysql_query("select id, lockState,name from register_db where Id=1");
$items = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    array_push($items, $row);
}
echo json_encode($items);
```

Result from query

```
[{"id":"1","lockState":"No","name":"Local Application"}]
```

Index.php

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "feed/lockState.php",
            data: ({id: 1}),
            cache: false,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));  // [{"id":"1","lockState":"No","name":"Local Application"}]
                alert(response.name); //***undefined***
                  if(response.name=='Local Application'){
                     callMyFunction(response.name);
                   }
          },
            error: function () {
               alert("Oops..!! Something wrong!);

            }
        });
```

I'm totally lost where I'm doing wrong in using 'Success' response. Even I tried to `JSON.parse(response)` and tried to access the key:value, but still same `undefined`. Please help.

Comment: because it is an array, not an object.

Comment: `response` is an array

Comment: In situations like this, you can do `console.log(response)` to get a nice representation of the variable in the error console.

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Hello Quentin, Yes I'm using the latest version, however it was a old application still in use which will we are working to replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response[0].name` will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your PHP. See `$items = array();` where you create an array.

Look at the data you are getting. See the `[` and `]` around it.

You have an **array** containing an object. You need to read the first value out of that array.

```
var object = response[0];
var name = object.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you tried would work if the response was:

```
{"id":"1","lockState":"No","name":"Local Application"}
```

But your response is:

```
*[*{"id":"1","lockState":"No","name":"Local Application"}*]*
```

The brackets mean the response is an array, [], containing an object, {};

As others have mentioned; the way to retrieve values out of an array can be done by using array_variable[0] to for example select the first.

In your example try this:

```
 alert(response[0].name); //***undefined***
```